# how to make sure only certain checkboxes are checked and others are unchecked using ischecked() method in android

Tags: java, android

Am developing a quiz app and I am trying to make sure only 2 checkbox is checked out of the 4 checkbox what method should I use to make sure certain checkbox are unchecked.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `CheckBox.isChecked()` will return whether specific checkbox is checked, or not.

Comment: I tried to save the ischecked() return value to a Boolean variable but how to make sure the checkbox is unchecked

Comment: Don't you see obvious thing - if it is `NOT checked`, then it is `UNCHECKED`? if CheckBox.isChecked() returns `false`, then the checkbox is not checked

Comment: @ArunJagadish please answer to these questions. How many checkboxes do you have? Is there a button which the user has to hit to "submit" some answers? Do you want to have a minimum number of checked checkboxes before the user can submit?

Comment: @Tony I am having four CheckBox and i have to make sure only the 1st and 3rd CheckBox is checked and 2nd and 4th is kept unchecked how i should i use my if statement to make sure only the 1st and 3rd is checked

Comment: @Tony Thanks i got the answer its !isChecked(). Thanks For Trying To Help Me :)

Answer (score 0):

make checkbox in xml

```
 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/c1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/chk_android"
    android:checked="true" />
```

like this make two in which check is true and for other two check in false and then use isChecked() method in activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if ***first*** and ***third*** check box **checked** &&
***second*** and ***fourth*** are **unchecked** then use this function :

> Assume **checkBox1** is the **first** checkbox
>
> Assume **checkBox2** is the **second** checkbox
>
> Assume **checkBox3** is the **third** checkbox
>
> Assume **checkBox4** is the **fourth** checkbox

```
private void doTheJob(){

        if(checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox3.isChecked() &&
           !checkBox2.isChecked() && !checkBox4.isChecked())

           //do stuff
    }
```

> Then call doTheJob() wherever you like.

**Explanation :**

isChecked() **returns** a **boolean**, that means **true** or **false**.

If the checkbox is **checked**, then this boolean will return **true**.

If the checkbox is **not** **checked**, then this boolean will return **false**.

Using **!** before a boolean   means the opposite. In our case it means, if it is NOT checked .